# UDP сервер на epoll

Tags: linux, сервер, udp, epoll

В интернете в общем с разных мест понашкрябывал код и сам немного прочитав чего-то добавил но вот про udp маловато информации и мне немного не понятно как правильно обрабатывать события на сокетах, а именно в этом месте:

```
    int events_count;
while (1) {
    events_count = epoll_wait(server.epoll.fd, server.epoll.events, EPOLL_MAXEVENTS, -1);
    for (int i = 0; i < events_count; i++) {
        /* Вот тут я не знаю что писать. Мне нужно получить данные от клиента и отправить ему в ответ данные, как это сделать? И не для tcp, а udp*/

    }
}
```

Полный код вот http://pastebin.com/upTHCpcM

Может кто пояснить на пальцах как мне получить данные и отправить в ответ данные?

Comment: Как обычно. `recvfrom()/sendto()`. Только я что-то не увидел (наверное невнимательно код смотрел) откуда берутся новые сокеты, которые надо добавлять в epoll?

Comment: Если покажете как вы заполняете структуру events подскажу. Но по большому счёту epoll для UDP излишество, т.к. сокеты тут не "размножаются" как в TCP accept-ом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторю, для одного серверного UDP сокета, epoll излишество.

```
for (int i = 0; i < events_count; i++) {
          /* для Вашего случая */
        rcvsz = recvfrom(server.epoll.events[i].data.fd, &buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_DONTWAIT, (struct sockaddr *)&rmtadr, &rmtadrsz);
    if(rcvsz <= 0)
    {
      if(errno == EAGAIN) continue;
      close(server.epoll.events[i].data.fd);
    }
    /* Тут обрабатываем, если надо отвечаем, если обработка длительная, лучше чтоб потоков было несколько. */
    sendto(server.epoll.events[i].data.fd, &data, sizedata, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&rmtadr, rmtadrsz);
    }
```

Как-то так, некоторые моменты не раскрыты.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, все понял, epoll эфективен только при большом количестве сокетов которые нужно мониторить на события.

Comment: Выгоднее делать recvfrom из нескольких потоков.